# Need a simple multi threaded Flume source

Tags: java, multithreading, interceptor, flume

Looking for advice on how to setup a simple multi-threaded flume source.

I have been using a spoolDir source in my local dev environment to test my interceptors, but from the link below, it looks like spoolDir sources will always be single threaded:

[Reading Flume spoolDir in parallel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25875574/reading-flume-spooldir-in-parallel)

We have an interceptor that may be buggy in production because its using a non thread safe SimpleDateFormatter and I'm trying to reproduce in my simple dev environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was eventually able to reproduce the multithreaded buggy behavior we were seeing in production by switching my dev environment from a spoolDir source to a syslogtcp source.  The bug wasn't what we expected, it had nothing to do with SimpleDateFormatter and rather was how it was inserting additional info in event headers.

I simulated a syslog server by using nc (netcat) to send data to the syslog port.  I verified that the interceptor was getting called by more than one thread by logging the Thread name and ID.

So for anyone interested, its probably best to test your interceptors using a multithreaded source like syslogtcp rather than a spoolDir source.